# How to identify records where one ID column matches in both rows, and another column is populated in one record but not the other?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Example data:

| some_parent_id | some_parent_name | some_subset_name | some_subset_id | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | SPECIAL | special_shop | 9876 | 1234 road st |
| null | null | special_shop | 9876 | 1234 road st |
| 654321 | NOT_SPECIAL | not_special_shop | 9877 | 1258 diff st |
| 654321 | NOT_SPECIAL | not_special_shop | 9877 | 1258 diff st |

I would like to find a query that returns only the below results - so only if there are 2 total records for some_subset_id, and only if one record has a null some_parent_id and the other record has a non-null some_parent_id.

| some_parent_id | some_parent_name | some_subset_name | some_subset_id | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | SPECIAL | special_shop | 9876 | 1234 road st |
| null | null | special_shop | 9876 | 1234 road st |

The table I'm working with has well over 2 million records, and there are intentional duplicates, but unfortunately no unique identifier for rows. I did not create the table.

Comment: have all your rows thata you are searching the same structure where the firs both columns are nissing?

Comment: @nbk No, the rows are variable in that some have multiple or all columns filled in, and some rows have little to no data filled in.

Comment: You need to add more rows so that a pattern arrives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use analytic function in a subquery to filter your data (WHERE clause). The subquery defines the SELECTION column with values of IN or OUT so you can use it to fetch the rows marked as either of the values.

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl
WHERE   SUBS_ID IN  (   Select  SUBS_ID
                        From (  Select  SUBS_ID "SUBS_ID", CASE WHEN Count(SUBS_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBS_ID) > 1 And P_ID Is Null THEN 'OUT' ELSE 'IN' END "SELECTION"
                                From    tbl  )
                        Group By  SUBS_ID
                        Having    Max(SELECTION) = 'OUT' )
ORDER BY  SUBS_ID, P_ID NULLS LAST
```

With your sample data...

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 123456 "P_ID", 'SPECIAL'     "P_NAME", 'Special Shop'     "SUBS_NAME", 9876 "SUBS_ID", '1234, Road St.' "ADDRESS" From Dual Union All
            Select Null   "P_ID",  Null         "P_NAME", 'Special Shop'     "SUBS_NAME", 9876 "SUBS_ID", '1234, Road St.' "ADDRESS" From Dual Union All
            Select 654321 "P_ID", 'NOT_SPECIAL' "P_NAME", 'Not Special Shop' "SUBS_NAME", 9877 "SUBS_ID", '1234, Road St.' "ADDRESS" From Dual Union All
            Select 654321 "P_ID", 'NOT_SPECIAL' "P_NAME", 'Not Special Shop' "SUBS_NAME", 9877 "SUBS_ID", '1234, Road St.' "ADDRESS" From Dual
        )
```

... and with ' ***Having    Max(SELECTION) = 'OUT'*** ' result is:

| P_ID | P_NAME | SUBS_NAME | SUBS_ID | ADDRESS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | SPECIAL | Special Shop | 9876 | 1234, Road St. |
|  |  | Special Shop | 9876 | 1234, Road St. |

... and with ' ***Having    Max(SELECTION) = 'IN'*** ' result is:

| P_ID | P_NAME | SUBS_NAME | SUBS_ID | ADDRESS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 654321 | NOT_SPECIAL | Not Special Shop | 9877 | 1234, Road St. |
| 654321 | NOT_SPECIAL | Not Special Shop | 9877 | 1234, Road St. |

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
select
   a.*
from
   mytable as a
   inner join
   (
   select
      some_subset_id,
      sum(case when some_parent_id is null then 0 else 1 end) as have_parent_id,
      sum(case when some_parent_id is null then 1 else 0 end) as do_not_have_parent_id
   from
      mytable
   group by
      some_subset_id
   having
      sum(case when some_parent_id is null then 0 else 1 end) = 1
      and sum(case when some_parent_id is null then 1 else 0 end) = 1
   ) as b on b.some_subset_id = a.some_subset_id;
```