# Subquery in where statement returns more than just null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

EDIT: Didn't realize the original post was in oracle however this question still remains.

I was attempting to answer another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74620653/how-to-identify-records-where-one-id-column-matches-in-both-rows-and-another-co) as I thought I could answer it. Turns out I came to a solution but don't know why this works.

The question was how do you return rows where the ***subset_ID*** is the same but one record has data in the ***Parent*** columns and the other record(s) don't have data in the ***Parent*** columns?
The original table looks like this (unfortunately not much more to go off of):

| Parent_ID | Parent_Name | Subset_Name | Subset_ID | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | SPECIAL | special_shop | 9876 | 1234 road st |
| NULL | NULL | special_shop | 9876 | 1234 road st |
| 654321 | NOT_SPECIAL | not_special_shop | 9877 | 1258 diff st |
| 654321 | NOT_SPECIAL | not_special_shop | 9877 | 1258 diff st |

The solution would look like below:

| Parent_ID | Parent_Name | Subset_Name | Subset_ID | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | SPECIAL | special_shop | 9876 | 1234 road st |
| NULL | NULL | special_shop | 9876 | 1234 road st |

The solution I came up with that gives the above result is:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM #Sometable
WHERE 
Subset_ID in (SELECT ST2.Subset_ID FROM #Sometable ST2 WHERE ST2.Parent_ID IS NULL) 
AND 
Subset_ID in (SELECT ST3.Subset_ID FROM #Sometable ST3 WHERE ST3.Parent_Name IS NULL)
```

Why does this work when just the subquery ran alone returns:

| Parent_ID | Parent_Name | Subset_Name | Subset_ID | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | special_shop | 9876 | 1234 road st |

Would this always work and why does it work? If not always what are the edge cases?

Comment: The other post you mention is tagged for oracle, and this one is for sql-server, which is a microsoft product. Are the tags correct?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out I will update this post to indicate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery is basically only used to find the relevant `Subset_ID`s. As your subquery results show, only one Subset_ID is relevant (9876) in the source data. When used in the `WHERE` clause, you're saying, "return all the records from `#Sometable` where the `Subset_ID = 9876`". In the source data, there are only 2 records with `Subset_ID` = 9876 and they are both returned.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding fully. When the sub query is ran separately `WHERE Parent_ID is null` only returns the null record. How does the ***IN*** operator find the other record with the `Parent_ID` populated?

Comment: Ignore the fact that the Parent_ID is null. In that record, the Subset_ID is not null. That's the important piece of info used in the main WHERE.

Comment: @Snacknpack Well, you are not being entirely truthful. Your subquery does not return the entire row you say, but rather only the 9876 datum. Thus, the query becomes : SELECT * from #Sometable WHERE Subset_ID in (9876).

Comment: I see what both of you are saying now. This would return more results than one would have wanted. Thank you for your help!